# Accessing Ubuntu-based VPS from my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC

Tags: server, ssh, vpn, vps

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC alongside Windows 8.1. My problem is, I want to connect to my Ubuntu VPS using my Ubuntu PC but it's not working.

I tried `ssh root@vps-ip-add` but nothing happens.

Is the command correct? or do I need to install something? Thanks for the info.

My vps is freshly-installed with Ubuntu 12.04. I am using a proxy to connect my pc to the internet.

Comment: If you're using windows, are you able to log in as root? You may need to specify which port you want to connect on with the `-p` flag

Comment: I can login to my vps on windows via putty

Comment: Can you ping the IP Address? with `ping 0.0.0.0` where 0.0.0.0 is your VPS's actual IP

Comment: it's not working either.

Comment: So the root of your problem is that you can't see the server, therefore you can't access it. My guess is that it's an issue with your VPS, but I'm  not sure. Make sure the VPS is running properly, make sure you're not making a typo in the IP address, etc

Comment: it's working perfectly. since I can use putty on my windows using those credentials I am using on ubuntu pc. Maybe this is because I am using proxy, though I apply the setting system wide

Comment: If it works properly through windows/putty when not changing anything it would then have to be something with your VPN settings

Answer (score -1):

You must install openssh-server on your ubuntu-vps

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/openssh-server.html

Comment: OP can connect to his VPS via PuTTY on windows - therefore this isn't the issue

Comment: Ok I did not know that!